# A Photo Stream For the Cloud using ASP.NET MVC and Azure Blob Storage

Tags: blob, azure-storage

The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. on upload 
 var container = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"]).CreateCloudBlobClient()
                .GetContainerReference(Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            container.CreateIfNotExists();

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with container name which you are referring (i.e. Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).

A container name must be a valid DNS name, conforming to the following naming rules:

1. Container names must start with a letter or number, and can contain only letters,
    numbers, and the dash (-) character.
2. Every dash (-) character must be immediately preceded and followed by a letter or
    number; consecutive dashes are not permitted in container names.
3. All letters in a container name must be lowercase.
4. Container names must be from 3 through 63 characters long.

For more information please go to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd135715.aspx).

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Comment: Yes Thanks that was it the user name had an uppercase letter fixed with Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToLower()